# When to use loop.add_signal_handler?

Tags: python-asyncio

I noticed the asyncio library has a `loop.add_signal_handler(signum, callback, *args)` method.

So far I have just been catching unix signals in the main file using the `signals` module in with my asynchronous code like this:

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, callback)

async def main():
    ...
```

Is that an oversight on my part?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `add_signal_handler` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.add_signal_handler) is sparse<sup>1</sup>, but looking at [the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1c3de541e64f75046b20cdd27bada1557e550bcd/Lib/asyncio/unix_events.py#L76), it appears that the main added value compared to [`signal.signal`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/signal.html#signal.signal) is that `add_signal_handler` will ensure that the signal *wakes up the event loop* and allow the loop to invoke the signal handler along with other queued callbacks and runnable coroutines.

> So far I have just been catching unix signals in the main file using the signals module [...] Is that an oversight on my part?

That depends on what the signal handler is doing. Printing a message or updating a global is fine, but if it is invoking anything in any way related to asyncio, it's most likely an oversight. A signal can be delivered at (almost) any time, including during execution of an asyncio callback, a coroutine, or even during asyncio's own bookkeeping.

For example, the implementation of [`asyncio.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html) freely assumes that the access to the queue is single-threaded and non-reentrant. A signal handler adding something to a queue using [`q.put_nowait()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio.Queue.put_nowait) would be disastrous if it interrupted an on-going invocation of `q.put_nowait()` on the same queue. Similar to typical race conditions experienced in multi-threaded code, an interruption in the middle of assignment to [`_unfinished_tasks`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1c3de541e64f75046b20cdd27bada1557e550bcd/Lib/asyncio/queues.py#L146) might well cause it to get incremented only once instead of twice (once for each `put_nowait`).

Asyncio code is [designed](https://glyph.twistedmatrix.com/2014/02/unyielding.html) for *cooperative* multi-tasking, where the points where a function may suspend defined are clearly denoted by the `await` and related keywords. The `add_signal_handler` function ensures that your signal handler gets invoked at such a point, and that you're free to implement it as you'd implement any other asyncio callback.

---

<sup>1</sup> When this answer was originally written, the `add_signal_handler` documentation was [briefer](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.add_signal_handler) than today and didn't cover the difference to `signal.signal` at all. This question prompted it getting [expanded](https://bugs.python.org/issue35465) in the meantime.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It's a subtle yet important detail that even though signals caught with `signal.signal()` are not executed in a separate thread, they interrupted `asyncio` in the middle of whatever it was doing, so anything not thread-safe is also not signal-safe when used that way.